# How to remove default class from BFormSelect or b-form-select in vue js?

Tags: forms, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have code below:

```
<b-form-select v-model="filterDuration"
               id="initialDurationSelect"
               :options="durationOptions"
               @@change="onChange($event)"
               plain="true">
</b-form-select>
```

This select option rendering as below:

```
<select id="initialDurationSelect" size="0" class="form-control">
   <option value="0">All</option>
   <option value="3">Last 3 Months</option>
   <option value="6">Last 6 Months</option>
</select>
```

I want to remove `class` attribute from this `select`, I have tried below options:

- add `class` as `class=""` (Not working and rendered as `class="form-control"`)
- add `class` as `class="123"` (Not working and rendered as `class="123 form-control"`)

Please suggest how to remove the `class` attribute or remove `"form-control"` from `class` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a native `<select>` element, and render the `<option>`s using a `v-for` loop.

BootstrapVue's components are designed to use bootstrap styling/classes. To render non Bootstrap style elements, just create the HTML5 elements yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use bootstrap-vue (and so Bootsrap CSS as well) as CSS framework to stylize and adjust your components on a web page then you should not use bootstrap-vue at all. All bootstrap-vue components uses some classes to be consistent with each other and with the whole design of a web page.

Comment: I am using the b-table component, so I can't remove the bootstrap-vue, is there any way to handle the default classes of bootstrap ?

Comment: Or you can try to remove/adjust unneccesary margins/paddings and other CSS props of a vue-select if you need this change only.